# ¿Como contar los ultimos registros que se ajusten a una condicion?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Quiero contar los últimos registros cuando cumplen que:

1. su `estado` es igual a 1
2. si el `usuario_id` es igual 5, y
3. el `test_id` es igual a 1

El número máximo de registros a contar es sólo 3.

Estos registros los tengo en una tabla con la siguiente estructura:

[image: Estructura de la tabla mysql]

Intenté con count() y limit de esta forma:

```
public function cuenta($usuarioID,$testID){
    $consulta = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
                   FROM (SELECT 1 
                           FROM repuestas 
                          WHERE estado = 1 
                            AND usuario_id = '$usuarioID' 
                            AND test_id = '$testID'
                          ORDER BY id DESC 
                          LIMIT 3,3) t";

    $resultado = $this->_db->query($consulta) or die(print_r($this->_db->errorInfo()));
    return $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

El problema que presenta esta consulta es que cuenta todos los que tengan estado en 1, y eso daría 3 (por el limit 3).

Pero si observan la imagen en los últimos 3 registros **sólo el 44 tiene estado en 1**, y eso me debería arrojar:

> que de entre los 3 últimos, sólo 1 tiene estado en 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que quieres encontrar los últimos 3 registros para una combinación específica de `usuario_id` y `test_id`. Y, luego, de entre esos 3 últimos registros, deseas contar cuántas tienen `estado_id = 1`.

Si entendí bien la pregunta, entonces esta es la consulta SQL que necesitas:

```sql
select count(case when estado_id = 1 then 'X' end)
  from (select estado_id
          from repuestas
         where usuario_id = 5 -- aquí usarías $usuarioID, estoy usando 5 como ejemplo.
           and test_id = 1 -- aquí usarías $testID, estoy usando 1 como ejemplo.
         order by id desc
         limit 3) t
```

o esta también es equivalente:

```sql
select count(*)
  from (select estado_id
          from repuestas
         where usuario_id = 5 -- aquí usarías $usuarioID, estoy usando 5 como ejemplo.
           and test_id = 1 -- aquí usarías $testID, estoy usando 1 como ejemplo.
         order by id desc
         limit 3) t
 where estado_id = 1
```

**SQL integrado con tu código PHP**

```
public function cuenta($usuarioID,$testID){
    $consulta = "select count(case when estado = 1 then 'X' end) as total 
                   from (select estado_id
                           from repuestas 
                          where usuario_id = '$usuarioID' 
                            and test_id = '$testID'
                          order by id desc
                          limit 3) t";

    $resultado = $this->_db->query($consulta) or die(print_r($this->_db->errorInfo()));
    return $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

o...

```
public function cuenta($usuarioID,$testID){
    $consulta = "select count(*) as total 
                   from (select estado_id
                           from repuestas 
                          where usuario_id = '$usuarioID' 
                            and test_id = '$testID'
                          order by id desc
                          limit 3) t
                  where estado_id = 1";

    $resultado = $this->_db->query($consulta) or die(print_r($this->_db->errorInfo()));
    return $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: En realidad `$usuarioID` y `$testID` lo determinará el valor que venga en la variable. En este caso tiene pinta de ser siempre el mismo pero no sabemos si el resto de la tabla tiene otros valores distintos para esos dos campos o no.

Comment: @Error404: Claro, y OP puede usar las variables en su código. Mi respuesta se concentra en el SQL, sin preocuparme de las variables. Pero voy a ajustar mi respuesta para aclarar. Gracias.

Comment: la variable `$usuarioID` varia con respecto al usuario que haya entrado en el sistema y `$testID` lo determina el test que presente dicho usuario el codigo ya fue implementado y funciona de mil maravillas solo que `estado_id` no se porque decia que no existia se lo cambie por `*` y funciono mil gracias :D

Comment: @jsoe: Tal vez aun tenías `select 1`. Como puedes ver, yo lo cambié a `select estado_id`. Me alegra que te haya funcionado.

Comment: Me quitaste la aceptada jejeje. Sospeché sobre el `select 1` y le pregunté pero como me acepto la respuesta pensé que eso era algo que se había creado él para la consulta aunque me pareciera muy raro xD

Comment: @Error404: Disculpa :)  Aunque te diré que el `select 1` no era el problema, funciona bien combinado con `select count(*)`. Pero mi respuesta ajusta el `select count(*)` a un `select count(case ...)`, que es la parte importante. Y con ese ajuste, ya no se puede usar `select 1`, si no que hay que devolver por lo menos `estado_id`.

Comment: No tienes de que disculparte :) En realidad desconocia lo del 1 y el `select count(case...)`, no tengo demasiada experiencia con mysql todavía, solo para defenderme pero me alegra aprender cada día un poco más 

Answer (score 1):

La consulta siempre te va a dar como resultado 3 debido a que estás usando `estado = 1` como filtro. Por mucho que utilices `limit 3` te va a coger los tres últimos registros que tengan `estado = 1`, es decir, los que tienen id 44, 43 y 42 ya que no tienes en cuenta los registros que tienen `estado = 0`.

Simplemente elimina de tu consulta `estado = 1`.

Además, otro error que he encontrado en tu consulta es el LIMIT que tienes. Tu lo tienes como `LIMIT 3,3` o lo que es lo mismo, `LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3`. Por lo tanto, tu consulta cogerá los últimos tres registros empezando por el cuarto por el final (cogiendo los id 43, 42 y 41, los cuales tienen `estado = 1`).

Para arreglarla del todo pon simplemente `LIMIT 3`.

Tu consulta final quedaría como:

```
$consulta = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (SELECT 1 FROM repuestas WHERE usuario_id = '$usuarioID' AND test_id = '$testID' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) t";
```

Comment: Ya lo probe y me arrojo 3 bueno 
si tengo algo asi:
estado
 0
 0
 1
me diria que solo hay uno en cambio si tengo algo asi:
estado
 0
 1
 1
me diria que tengo 2 y si fuera
estado 
 1 
 1
 1 
me diria que tengo 3 eso es lo que quiero que haga mi consulta :D.

Comment: @jsoejose Tengo una duda. ¿Porque haces `SELECT 1`? Ahora estoy revisando tu consulta de nuevo.

Comment: @jsoejose Por cierto, ¿que te devuelve el valor '$testID'?

Comment: bueno esa variable '$testID' me de vuelve 5 y el `SELECT 1` lo pongo por que la consulta que ves entre los parentesis la optuve de esta pagina  
[combinar count(*) y limit](http://developando.com/blog/mysql-combinar-count-limit) y la modifique un poquito :D

Answer (score 0):

> el problema que tengo es que no cuenta los ultimos tres registros si
>   no los ultimos 3 que su estado sea 1 y arroja que tengo 3 cuando en
>   realidad deberia arrojar 1. desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda que
>   puedan prestar :D

Entonces elimina `WHERE estado = 1` Ya que estás indicando en la consulta que solo considere los registros con estado igual a 1.

Comment: ya esta echo y la consulta queda asi

`public function cuenta($usuarioID,$testID){
        $consulta = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (SELECT 1 FROM repuestas WHERE usuario_id = '$usuarioID' AND test_id = '$testID' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3,3) t";
        $resultado = $this->_db->query($consulta) or die(print_r($this->_db->errorInfo()));
        return $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }` pero a un me sigue diciendo que son 3 y no uno, sera que le hace falta un distinc?